# netbeans IDE doesn't indent my SQL code

Tags: netbeans, ide, indentation

I've been searching for a good IDE for awhile and it seems netbeans is great. Everything looks and works nice, but I can't get it to indent sql code (possibly others, but this is all I've noticed thus far.

I don't really *need* it to auto-indent, but when I set the indentation level for a block, the next line just goes back to zero indentation, and I have to tab out every line.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that this can be done. In netbeans 6.9, under `Tools>>Options>>Editor>>Formatting` then `Language`, I only see `C, C++, Fortran, Java, JavaFX, PHP` as options to set formatting.